# Java Pattern.matches() returns wrong result

Tags: java, regex

I tried the code below in Java but I think its wrong:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[A-z]+", "1d"));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", "1d"));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[A-z]+", "1"));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", "d"));
    }
}
```

And I expected this output:

```
true
true
false
false
```

but I got this output:

```
false
false
false
false
```

Why is the output of Java wrong?

Comment: `matches` is not a search, it needs to match the entire expression

Comment: Also, [Regex to match only letters](//stackoverflow.com/a/3617808)

Comment: Your regexs are not correct, what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: The regex isn't wrong. Pattern.matches() only does not do what I have expected